# windows "open command window here" gives wrong environment

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

I often use the right-click "open command window here" feature of Windows-7, but just found a problem where the environment it gives is different than what I get on running cmd from the start line, or from the start menu cmd.

Specifically for me there are things which are in my PATH (verified from MyComputer/properties/advanced/environment) which are missing in the right-click environment, correctly present in the others.

Why? Any easy fix?

W7 seems to use the command: cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"
for the right-click option.

It seems that there are multiple cmd.exe’s around, one is C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, another in c:\Windows\sysWOW64, and a few others lying around under c:/Windows, but both give the wrong PATH environment. I am not sure what the start-menu cmd actually starts!

Comment: Hmm, sorry if the wrong place to post, I saw several very similar (378319, 60904, 5724, ...) - I'm happy to migrate to another place on the forum if more appropriate.

Comment: No problem. :-) They probably were here before there was a SuperUser. When things expanded from StackOverflow to the StackExchange group of sites, new places appeared and posts started being referred/migrated to them, but the old posts are still here. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) was updated to show what types of questions are appropriate here now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by restarting explorer.exe.

I think the issue I ran into was that I edited %PATH%, but explorer was using a stale version of it.

This will also happen if you already have a command window open when you edit an environment variable: the changes don't reflect in the window that is already open, **only in new windows that are created.**